# Datatable LWC tbody in another component

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable

I am trying to use another component in tbody for a custom data Table in LWC
when i use /iterate records in tbody , it is renderinng fine and giving expected result

> Single Component

```
<template>
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
            <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name">Opportunity Name</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Close Date">Close Date</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Stage">Stage</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
            <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">
                <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Cloudhub</a>
              </div>
            </th>
            <td data-label="Account Name">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">Cloudhub</div>
            </td>
            <td data-label="Close Date">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/14/2015">4/14/2015</div>
            </td>
            <td data-label="Prospecting">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Prospecting">Prospecting</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
            <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">
                <a href="#" tabindex="-1">DataView</a>
              </div>
            </th>
            <td data-label="Account Name">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">DataAccount</div>
            </td>
            <td data-label="Close Date">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/14/2015">1/14/2018</div>
            </td>
            <td data-label="Prospecting">
              <div class="slds-truncate" title="Prospecting">Negotiations</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

But when i put all body  code in another component,

> PARENT CMP

```
<template>
<table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
            <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name">Opportunity Name</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Close Date">Close Date</div>
            </th>
            <th class="" scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Stage">Stage</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c-data-table-entries></c-data-table-entries>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> CHILD CMP

```
<template>
<tr class="slds-hint-parent">
    <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">
        <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Cloudhub</a>
      </div>
    </th>
    <td data-label="Account Name">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">Cloudhub</div>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Close Date">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/14/2015">4/14/2015</div>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Prospecting">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="Prospecting">Prospecting</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="slds-hint-parent">
    <th data-label="Opportunity Name" scope="row">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">
        <a href="#" tabindex="-1">DataView</a>
      </div>
    </th>
    <td data-label="Account Name">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="Cloudhub">DataAccount</div>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Close Date">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="4/14/2015">1/14/2018</div>
    </td>
    <td data-label="Prospecting">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="Prospecting">Negotiations</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

it is rendering like below

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because you have another element in the structure, the child component, with its shadow DOM. The output (ignoring shadow DOM boundaries) is structured something like this:

```
<c-parent>
  <table>
    ...
    <tbody>
      <c-data-table-entries>
        <tr>
          <td>...</td>
          ...
        </tr>
        ...
     </c-data-table-entries>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</c-parent>
```

Because there is a non-tabular element between the table body and the rows, the browser cannot render the table as you expect.

Making sure that `c-data-table-entries` is declared, via CSS, to render as a table row group should let the browser render correctly. Do this by adding the following to your `c-data-table-entries` LWC's CSS:

```
:host {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

You need to also remove `tbody` from the parent, since the `table-row-group` CSS represents a `tbody` and the child component is now rendered as the `tbody` via CSS instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried as you said  but unfortunately its not working :(

Comment: You did both the CSS and remove the tbody?

Comment: I have added this 
:host {
  display: table-row-group;
}

, only in child

Comment: Remove the tbody from the parent too as covered in the answer.

Comment: Yes i already did that, but its still showing same

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to add the generated markup for this part of the Lightning page? Use the browser's DOM inspector to get this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133228/discussion-between-swarandeep-singh-and-phil-w).

Comment: Well its 2022, and it worked, thanks!

Comment: @NikhilZurunge feel free to upvote :)

Comment: indeed! @PhilW :)